# Inline CSS HTML5 attribute within link_to string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Here's a `link_to` I'd like to add a custom HTML5 attribute to part of the string. Like this:

```
link_to "Awesome<Bold>Sauce</Bold>", root_path, :class => "logo"
```

Current output is: `Awesome<Bold>Sauce</Bold>` Obviously should be: Awesome **Sauce**

**Any ideas?**

> *This works but I'm looking to do it inline if possible.*
>
> ```
> link_to "Awesome", root_path, :class => "logo"
> link_to "Sauce", root_path, :class => "Bold"
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `raw`:

```
link_to raw("Awesome<Bold>Sauce</Bold>"), root_path, :class => "logo"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the preferred convention:

```
<%= link_to root_path, class: "logo" do %>
  Awesome<strong>Sauce</strong>
<% end %>
```